# React component chrome extension shows my State has a string but when I log it or send to the database this doesn`t exist

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to 1. Upload a photo to cludinary 2. Get the response from cloudinary with the url where the photo is uploaded 3. Save this photo url as string in react State 4. Send and object with more info and the photo url to a mongo DB database.

Points 1 and 2 work perfectly fine, point 3 works in console.log(response.data.secure_url) but when I set the url in the state and I console.log the Object, the url doesnt appear!. It only appears in google chrome react extension. Point 4 also works fine if I set the photo in mongoose as not required, and the object is sent to the database without the url information.

OBJECT TO SEND TO DATABASE

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    title: "",
    tags: "",
    photo: "",
    description: "",
    likes: 1,
    user: auth.user?.email,
  });
```

FUNCTION THAT HANDLES ALL THE POINTS

```
const uploadImage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.title && form.tags && imageSelected && form.description) {
      setGeneratingImg(true);
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", imageSelected);
      formData.append("upload_preset", "bfexi6se");
      try {
        async function requestsFn() {
          console.log("start axios");
          await axios
            .post(
              "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dg4ieuvqx/image/upload",
              formData
            )
            .then(async (response) => {
              console.log("form before setForm", form);
              console.log(response.data.secure_url);
              console.log(response.data);
              console.log("form before url await response data", form);
              const url = response.data.secure_url;
              setForm({ ...form, photo: url });
              console.log("form after setForm", form);
              console.log("setForm finished");
            });
          console.log("finish axios");
          console.log("form after finish axios", form);
          await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form),
          });
          console.log("finish fetch");
          console.log("form after finish fetch", form);
        }

        requestsFn();

        setTimeout(() => {
          setUploaded(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            /* navigate("/home");*/
          }, 2000);
        }, 10000);

        setImageSelected("");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setUploadError(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setUploadError(false);
        }, 10000);
      } finally {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setGeneratingImg(false);
          console.log("form after 10 seconds", form);
        }, 10000);
      }
    } else {
      handleTitleError(form.title);
      handleTagsError(form.tags);
      handlePhotoError(imageSelected);
      handleDescriptionError(form.description);
    }

    console.log("form at last", form);
  };
```

I tried to see whats the reason why it would appear in react extension and console.log but not logging the Object of form.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be related to Chrome's extensions platform. Could you remove the "google-chrome-extension" flag?